# How can I convert array to an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have an array with a single element that looks like this `[{…}]`

All I have to do simply to convert this to an object like this `{}`

Comment: `[{...}}` and `{}` are not very descriptive. How do you want to convert the array to an object? If it is only one element why not just `arr[0]` ?

Comment: Because of TS complainings for ```arr[0]```.

Comment: I definitely remember that I can ```reduce``` this somehow, but I didn't manage to find a solution

Comment: What is the TypeScript error/warning about the use of `arr[0]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was `array.reduce((acc, x) => ({...acc,...x}))`

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer you are looking for is something like this:

```js
const arr = [
  {name: 'name', value: 1},
  {name: 'name2', value: 2},
  {name: 'name3', value: 3},
  {name: 'name4', value: 4},
  {name: 'name5', value: 5},
]

const arrToObj = arr.reduce((obj, el) => {
  obj[el.name] = el.value
  return obj
}, {})

console.log(arrToObj)
```